# Getting "Not a valid file format" when trying to parse an Excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, xls

I’m using Ruby 2.3 w with Rails 4.2.7.  I have this in my GEmfile …

```
gem 'creek'
```

I’m trying got parse an Excel (“.xls” not “.xlsx”) file, like so

```
sheet = creek.sheets[0]
sheet.rows.each do |row|
  my_object_time = service.create_my_object_time_obj(row, race_id)
  if my_object_time.valid?
    results.push(my_object_time)
  else
     puts "#{my_object_time.errors.full_messages}"
  end
```

but I get the error…

```
RuntimeError: Not a valid file format.
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/creek-1.1.2/lib/creek/book.rb:20:in `initialize'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/xls_to_my_object_times_converter_service.rb:13:in `new'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/xls_to_my_object_times_converter_service.rb:13:in `get_my_object_times'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/xls_processor_service.rb:15:in `process_page_data'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:83:in `process_race_data'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

on the line “creek = Creek::Book.new file_location”.  What gives?  I’m open to using another gem to parsing the Excel file if it can parse a sheet and give me cells and values in a hash format.

Comment: You are trying to parse an xls format but creek parses only xlsx format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `Not a valid file format` is pretty self explanatory.

Creek [documentation](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/creek) tells you in the title that it's a

> Stream parser for large Excel(xlsx and xlsm) files.

I've had good experience with [spreadsheet](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet) gem.

Answer (score 0):

Since others might end up at the same point without the simple explanation that the file is not an xlsx-file I thought I'd add that the "Not a valid file format" gets thrown based on file extension and there is an option to ignore said extension, like this:

```
Creek::Book.new path, check_file_extension: false
```

(Example taken from the creek test_spec)